# React project firebase deploy showing welcome screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, deployment

Deployed my react app on firebase through my VS code terminal, on clicking the url generated, it's showing me the attached firebase welcome screen. Please who knows how I can fix this [the screen I'm getting after deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VLYc.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! One way you could be seeing this is that you haven't uploaded the correct resources. Can you check your `firebase.json` file and verify that your hosting.public folder is set to where you build your react app?

Comment: Yes. My public folder on firebase.json is set to build

Comment: I can't remember exactly but you should be able to check that your build folder contains the correct index.html file (and not the one created by firebase init) and when you deploy using firebase script it should show you what it is uploading. Are your other files uploaded correctly?

Comment: And how exactly am I supposed to do that please, can you share a format?

Answer (score 1):

You've probably overwrote your `index.html` file in public folder.

If you use git just pull the older version of `index.html` if not just create a new react app and copy the code over. Now comes the deployment:

Delete these files/folders:

- .firebase folder
- .firebaserc
- firebase.json

Now initialize hosting

```sh
firebase init hosting
```

When you're prompted to to provide a public directory choose `build`
When it say file `build/index.html` already exists. Overwrite? enter a big no

```sh
? Please select an option: Use an existing project
? Select a default Firebase project for this directory: portfolio-a8639 (portfolio)
i  Using project portfolio-a8639 (portfolio)

? What do you want to use as your public directory? build
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
? Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? Yes
? File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of build/index.html
```

Now you're ready to deploy:

```sh
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

If you don't have a build folder just build the project:

```sh
$ npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all delete your **build folder** **.firebase**, **.firebaserc**, **firebase.json**, **package-lock.json** .

Now write the command  `firebase init`
then follow the steps below -

- What do you want to use as your public directory? build ?
- Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
- Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No
- File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite? Yes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue almost 3 years later too. While the cause in my case was probably quite different to what it was when this question was asked, it might help others anyway in the future.

The problem I faced was that during `firebase init hosting` an index.html and 404.html were generated to the public folder and after `firebase deploy` that static index.html was what was delivered. The link between index.html and index.js was somehow missing.

In the end I explicitly declared firebase-tools dependency to the most current version (most current was 13.1.0, while before version 12.4.4 was used due to the transitive dependency via firebaseui). With the newer firebase-tools version I deleted .firebaserc, firebase.json and .firebase directory, then re-initialized/re-deployed with `firebase init hosting` and `firebase deploy`.
During initialization there was the new question asked which I suppose made the difference:

```
=== Hosting Setup
? Detected an existing Next.js codebase in the current directory, should we use this?
```

The answer to the question was `Y` of course.